# Tried to code a Matrix, but Java reports an issue

Tags: java, math, matrix

I tried to code a matrix in Java.
I'm only allowed to use long for creating 2d arrays, but Java reports an issue that states: "The operator < is undefined for the argument type(s) int, long[]."
It would be nice if someone could review my code down below.

Here's my code:

```java
public class Matrix {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int length;
        int width;
        int[][] matrix;
        matrix[width][length] = 0;

        long[][] matrix1 = new long[width][length];
        for (int i = width; i < matrix1.length; i++) {
            for (int j = length; j < matrix1[i]; j++) {
                matrix1[i][j] = j;
            }
        }

        System.out.println(matrix1[2][3]);
    }

}
```

Java should print out the following result:

```
Input: (matrix1[2][3])

Output: 0 0 0
        0 0 0
```

Comment: `j<matrix1[i]` should be `j<matrix1[i].length`. `matrix1[i]` is still an array.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you do the same in the firest `for`. To get width of the matrix (i.e. get length of the given row in the matrix), you have to get length of the array of the row:

```
public static void main(String... args) {
    int width = 4;
    int height = 4;
    long[][] matrix = new long[height][width];

    for (int row = 0; row < matrix.length; row++)
        for (int col = 0; col < matrix[row].length; col++)  // matrix[row] is an 1D array
            matrix[row][col] = col;

    System.out.println(matrix[2][3]);
    SYstem.out.println(Arrays.toString(matrix[2]));  // print the row 3
}
```

Comment: that only gives "3".  but it needs to be a 2d matrix, including e.g. width: 2 , length: 3 and the console has to send a 2x3 matrix.

Comment: You want to print a whole row?

Comment: yes. it must be a row, fields must include numbers like zeros.

Comment: it goes to the right direction, thanks. but it still only print out a 1 x 4 matrix. it must be a 2 x 3 matrix and the matrix should only consists of 0. a 2 x 3 matrix should have 3 zeros in the first line and 3 zeros in the second line.

Comment: Could you give an example in the question: inputs and outputs?

Comment: i add the input and the output now.